# Создание папки пользователя

Tags: php

Делаю проект подобие (Youtube)только в другом направлении.

Встал вопрос хранения файлов пользователя. В мануале PHP узнал, что можно создать папку для загрузки и чтения файлов. Есть вообще смысл создавать при авторизации пользователя папку для хранения файлов (видео , картинки)? Чтобы была именная папка и потом уже при загрузке файлов пользователя записывать в БД и уже выводить файлы из создаваемой папки пользователя на страницу сайта.

Скажу что в этом я новичок и только постигаю PHP.

Comment: Можете создать папку upload а в ней папки пользователя, можете все валить в одну кучу, можно файл хоть в бд запихать(не самый правильный вариант). Т.к. имена файлов обычно хранятся в бд, то доступ к файлам что из папки, что из подпапки одинаковый. Вопрос вашего удобства и порядка. Для красоты можно создать.

Comment: лучше равномерно разделять по папкам все файлы. возьмите какой нить `Y-m` от даты загрузки и `userId%100`, формируйте имя директории. Вообще оцените ожидаемый объем файлов, и решите стоит ли хранить файлы на своем хостинге, или вынести в облачный.

Comment: А насчет безопасности Upload  . Видел комментарий что если создавать такие папки  их могут любой школьник взломать .

Comment: Так не разрешай грузить файлы которые можно запустить из папки. Ограничь запуск файлов из папки.

Comment: Спасибо так и сделаю . А как же запретить если допустим я хочу что бы видео пользователя видели все ?

Comment: а при чем тут видео? вам пишут. что надо запретить загрузку, например, php-файлов.